# Null-coalesing or ternary operator prefernce?

Tags: c#, ternary, null-coalescing-operator

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Shift_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_Shift_Id;
```

p_Shift_Id could be null. If it is null, then I want to use DBNull.Value. If it's not null, then the value that it contains.

What is the best approach? I would rather not use

```
 if(p_Shift_Id == null)
 {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Shift_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DBNull.Value;
 } else {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Shift_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_Shift_Id;
 }
```

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Shift_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_Shift_Id ?? DBNull.Value;` What about this?

Comment: @TanvirArjel DataTypes are not compatible, needs typecast to object

Comment: @TanvirArjel can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `p_Shift_Id` as `object` and then use `Null-Coalescing` operator as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Shift_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = (object)p_Shift_Id ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: I think, casting to object needs to moved to DBNull.Value. p_Shift_Id will be casted to object via boxing.

Comment: @sam No problem! You can do it from both end.